# React Axios Appends Window Origin To Provided Url (json-server)

Tags: reactjs, axios, json-server

I have a weird behaviour while integrating a json-server api with axios.

I use json-server to serve a db.json file

```
json-server --watch db.json --port 4000
```

and in my react application I use axios to call "http://localhost:4000/tasks"

Testing it on postman, the API returns results and it is working fine.

but using the code snippet below (axios) it concatenates both domains of the react app and the api Url to the request.

```
try {
        return axios({
            method: 'GET',
            url: `http://localhost:4000/tasks`
        }).then((response) => {
            debugger;
            return response;
        });
    } catch (error) {
        return new Error('Failed to retrieve Tasks');
    }
```

I check in the browser network and I the request Url like that

Request URL: http://localhost:3000/http//localhost:4000/tasks

and therefore throws a not found - 404 exception

Any idea why is this happening?

The weird thing is that When I use another API like star wars api "https://swapi.co/api/people/1", It works like a charm.

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Hi, please check in your package.json if you have a proxy field. If yes change your proxy to http://localhost:4000/ and call get url like this: '/tasks'.

Or: delete proxy, and ur first code will work

Comment: I don't have a proxy field

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've fixed this problem by using environment variables.

I just created a ".env.development" file and added "REACT_APP_API_BASEURL = 'http://localhost:4000'".

And then I used it as follows:

```
try {
    return axios({
        method: 'GET',
        url: `${process.env.REACT_APP_API_BASEURL}/tasks`
    }).then((response) => {
        debugger;
        return response;
    });
} catch (error) {
    return new Error('Failed to retrieve Tasks');
}
```

and it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

Just faced this issue, it's because the url used in axios is wrong. In this case, the url in the original question is

```
http://localhost:3000/http//localhost:4000/tasks
```

Notice http//localhost:4000/tasks this is missing a colon after http. Fixing the url will fix this issue in case someone else is facing this again